# NonLinearFit running too slowly when the model contains an integral

Tags: plotting, fitting

I am new to *Mathematica* and am learning to use it. I have come up with the following situation where I have to fit the data.

```
0.02923 220.64
0.05846 213.2
0.08770 211.95
0.11693 212.39
0.14617 208.25
0.17540 205.5
0.21800 201.05
0.27674 195.149
0.34837 189.8
0.44944 170.6
0.61586 169.05
1.33788 141.
```

with a model consisting of integrals the code used for this purpose is attached below.

```
G = 4.3*10^-6;
n = 2.36;
re = 12.7*4.8481*10^-6*11.2*10^3;
io = 19.8*10^6;
b = (2*n) - 0.333 + (0.009876/n);

p := 1.0 - (0.6097/n) + (0.0403/n^2)
rho0[gamma_] := gamma*io*(Gamma[2 n]/Gamma[n (3 - p)])*(1/(2*re))*b^(n (1 - p))
rho1[r_, gamma_] := rho0[gamma]*(r/re)^(-p)*Exp[-b (r/re)^1/n]

m1[r_, gamma_]:= (4*Pi*rho0[gamma]*re^3*n)*Gamma[n*(3 - p), (r/re)^(1/n)]

m2[rho22_, r0_] := 6.4*rho22*r0^3
m21[r_, rho22_, r0_] := 
  m2[rho22, r0]*(Log[1 + (r/r0)] - ArcTan[r/r0] + (1/2)*Log[1 + (r/r0)^2])
m[r_, rho22_, gamma_, r0_] := m1[r, gamma] + m21[r, rho22, r0]
```

Here `rho22`, `gamma`, `r0` are free parameters which are to be determined from the fit of the following few lines of code to the data.

```
f1[r_?NumericQ, rho22_?NumericQ, gamma_?NumericQ, r0_?NumericQ] := 
  (G/rho1[r, gamma]) *
    NIntegrate[m[s, rho22, gamma, r0]*rho1[s, gamma]/s^2, {s, r, 1000}]
f2[R_?NumericQ, gamma_?NumericQ] := 
  2*NIntegrate[r*rho1[r, gamma]/(r^2 - R^2)^0.5, {r, R, 1000}]
f3[R_?NumericQ, rho22_?NumericQ, gamma_?NumericQ, r0_?NumericQ] := 
  Sqrt[(2/f2[R, gamma] *
    NIntegrate[
      f1[r, rho22, gamma, r0]*rho1[r, gamma]*r/(r^2 - R^2)^0.5, 
      {r, R, 1000}])]
```

Here the function `f3` is to be fit to the data, but `NonlinearModelFit` keeps on running without giving any output. It would be helpful if anyone could suggest a solution. The code used for fitting is as follows.

```
model = 
  NonlinearModelFit[
    data, 
    {f3[r, rho22, gamma, r0], r0 > 0}, 
    {{rho22, 10^6}, {gamma, 2}, {r0, 0.1}}, 
    r]
```

I tried fitting using the following code. It works but gives a lot of errors

```
model = 
      NonlinearModelFit[
        data, 
        f3[r, rho22, gamma, r0], 
        {rho22, gamma, r0}, 
        r]
```

The errors I get are given below.

```
Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>
NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in r near {r} = {0.047314576928149236661852549750595106568373987728475575}. NIntegrate obtained 3.7404877397937913930362819846457144317111876136553317`53.*^19.7404877397937913930362819846457144317111876136553317`53.* and 1.653989848295460580622379640065483547846262080138546`53.*^19 for the integral and error estimates. >>
NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in r near {r} = {0.10568773775691363884671521285755669304346305237452976}. NIntegrate obtained 1.2021665155137757150974883227856260543059972327085511`53.*^19.2021665155137757150974883227856260543059972327085511`53.* and 5.7355129592381038783878766186075727365381501501426807`53.*^18.7355129592381038783878766186075727365381501501426807`53.* for the integral and error estimates. >>
The function value {157493. +0. I,177463. +0. I,106252. +0. I,123857. +0. I,116620. +0. I,108502. +0. I,112147. +0. I,105784. +0. I,103182. +0. I,94371.2 +0. I,43730.5 +0. I,-141.+22940.5 I} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {12} at {rho0bur,gamma,r0} = {7.51812*10^7,95.822,-7.6518*10^7}. >>
```

it still gives an output which is really bad.

**Edit**

I have changed the model to give a better fit and it works fine with acceptable results. The code for which is given below.

```
g = 4.3*10^-6;
n = 2.36;
re = 0.892;
p = 1.0 - (0.6097/n) + (0.05563/n^2);
b = (2 n - 1)/3 + (0.009876/n);
rho1[r_, rho0_] := rho0*(r/re)^-p*Exp[-b (r/re)^(1/n)];
m0[rho0_] := 4*Pi*rho0*re^3*n*b^(n (p - 3));
m1[r_, rho0_] := m0[rho0]*(Gamma[n (3 - p), 0, b*(r/re)^(1/n)])
mh[rho0h_, r0_] := 6.4*rho0h*r0^3;
mh1[r_, rho0h_, r0_] := 
 mh[rho0h, 
   r0]*(Log[1 + (r/r0)] - ArcTan[r/r0] + (1/2)*Log[1 + (r/r0)^2])
m[r_, rho0_, rho0h_, r0_] := m1[r, rho0] + mh1[r, rho0h, r0]
```

then I fit the data below code.

```
unp1[r_?NumericQ, rho0h_?NumericQ, r0_?NumericQ, 
  rho0_?NumericQ] := (g/rho1[r, rho0])*
  NIntegrate[mh1[s, rho0h, r0]*rho1[s, rho0]/s^2, {s, r, 1000}]

sigmap[R_?NumericQ, rho0_?NumericQ] := 
 2*NIntegrate[rho1[r, rho0]*r/(r^2 - R^2)^0.5, {r, R, 1000}]

pro1[R_?NumericQ, rho0h_?NumericQ, r0_?NumericQ, 
  rho0_?NumericQ] := (2/sigmap[R, rho0])*
  NIntegrate[
   unp1[r, rho0h, r0, rho0]*rho1[r, rho0]*r/(r^2 - R^2)^0.5, {r, R, 
    1000}]

unp2[r_?NumericQ, rho0_?NumericQ] := (g/rho1[r, rho0])*
  NIntegrate[m1[s, rho0]*rho1[s, rho0]/s^2, {s, r, 1000}]
pro2[R_?NumericQ, rho0_?NumericQ] := (2/sigmap[R, rho0])*
  NIntegrate[
   unp2[r, rho0]*rho1[r, rho0]*r/(r^2 - R^2)^0.5, {r, R, 1000}]

pro[R_?NumericQ, rho0h_?NumericQ, r0_?NumericQ, rho0_?NumericQ] := 
 pro1[R, rho0h, r0, rho0] + pro2[R, rho0]

totalfit = 
 NonlinearModelFit[
  data, (pro[R, rho0h, r0, rho0])^0.5, {{rho0h, 
    5*10^11}, {r0, 0.1}, {rho0, 6*10^8}}, R, MaxIterations -> 10000, 
  EvaluationMonitor :> Print@{rho0h, r0, rho0}]
```

It works fine but takes around half an hour to converge. Is there a way to speed this up?

Thanking you.

Comment: Thanks for adding some data but if the issue is with `NonlinearModelFit`, you'll need to add the `NonlinearModelFit` command.  The issue could be a grammatical issue with the construction of the `NonlinearModelFit` command or it could be a data related issue with the options (such as starting values) used with `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: In the definition of `rho1` is the factor `Exp[-b (r/re)^1/n]` intended instead to be `Exp[-b (r/re)^(1/n)]`?  It is unusual to see something explicitly raised to the first power.

Comment: @BobHanlon yes, that is the factor. It is Exp[-b(r/re^(1/n))]

Comment: The best way for speeding up I can think of is to simplify the model: it involves 3 `NIntegrate`, too complex! If you add something like `EvaluationMonitor :> Print@{rho22, gamma, r0}` into `NonlinearModelFit`, you'll see `NonlinearModelFit` is indeed working, but very slow.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you very much for the reply I am trying to simplify the model

Comment: If it is possible, you should start with better starting values.  The above starting values produce  estimates nowhere near the observed values.  That might reduce the number of iterations that `NonlinearModelFit` needs.

Comment: @JimBaldwin  I have tried using Manipulate to find the best parameter's, but it does not work properly with the integral and the integral. It hangs a lot. I am searching for an Idea to do that properly.